# fitting a straight line on data X and Y taking into account the errors on X and Y

Tags: python

Could you please give me a hint on a python code which fits a straight line on data X and Y taking into account the errors on X and Y?

Comment: Do you mean that each point in X and Y has three numbers, [low, mean, high]?

Comment: each X and Y  point has a corresponding error,  Xerr, Yerror. For example,  X = [1,3,2], Xerror =[0.4,0.5,0.7], Y=[7,8,9], Yerror = [0.5,0.1,0.9]

Comment: Does this question on [Linear Regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42658190/plotting-one-sigma-error-bars-on-a-curve-fit-line-in-scipy) answers your question?